# How do I manually select the bandwidth in rdrobust?

Tags: r, rdd, bandwidth

I am using an election data frame with margin of victory as my running variable and I want to manually select the bandwidth in rdrobust.
I now that I should use the h() command for that, but I don't understand how to put two bandwidths.

I want 0.10 and -0.10 in both sides of the cutoff. This is my code:

```r
llr_outcome2 <- rdrobust::rdrobust(
  thesis_no_na$pre_natal,
  thesis_no_na$margin_of_victory, 
  c = 0,
  kernel = "tri",
  h = c(-0.1, 0.1))
summary(llr_outcome2)
```

and I get this error: `Error in rdrobust_kweight(X_l, c, h_l, kernel) : object 'h_l' not found`

Thank you for any help :)!

Comment: The package manual suggests that you can mention two bandwidths, may be try contacting authors on how to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe simply specifying .1 will automatically apply the bandwidth symmetrically around the cut-off (i.e. it will be between [-.1, 1]. You would only need to specify two if you wanted asymmetric cut-offs between the two sides.

This may solve your current issue, but more generally, I also could not figure out how to apply asymmetric bandwidths.